# ERROR (deploy:?): deploy in Sever Log

Tags: mirth, mirth-connect

I get the following error in the server log when I deploy a channel.  This seems to happen to all of my channels.  Despite this error, the channels still work as expected.

I'd like to track down why this is happening.  I've looked in the xml of the channels and nothing seems to be out of place.

Here's a stripped down channel that still shows the error:

```
<channel version="3.5.1">
  <id>b3c6c2ad-b6ef-4800-aff0-7ea61db1beef</id>
  <nextMetaDataId>2</nextMetaDataId>
  <name>Test for error</name>
  <description></description>
  <revision>1</revision>
  <sourceConnector version="3.5.1">
    <metaDataId>0</metaDataId>
    <name>sourceConnector</name>
    <properties class="com.mirth.connect.connectors.vm.VmReceiverProperties" version="3.5.1">
      <pluginProperties/>
      <sourceConnectorProperties version="3.5.1">
        <responseVariable>None</responseVariable>
        <respondAfterProcessing>true</respondAfterProcessing>
        <processBatch>false</processBatch>
        <firstResponse>false</firstResponse>
        <processingThreads>1</processingThreads>
        <resourceIds class="linked-hash-map">
          <entry>
            <string>Default Resource</string>
            <string>[Default Resource]</string>
          </entry>
        </resourceIds>
        <queueBufferSize>1000</queueBufferSize>
      </sourceConnectorProperties>
    </properties>
    <transformer version="3.5.1">
      <elements/>
      <inboundDataType>RAW</inboundDataType>
      <outboundDataType>RAW</outboundDataType>
      <inboundProperties class="com.mirth.connect.plugins.datatypes.raw.RawDataTypeProperties" version="3.5.1">
        <batchProperties class="com.mirth.connect.plugins.datatypes.raw.RawBatchProperties" version="3.5.1">
          <splitType>JavaScript</splitType>
          <batchScript></batchScript>
        </batchProperties>
      </inboundProperties>
      <outboundProperties class="com.mirth.connect.plugins.datatypes.raw.RawDataTypeProperties" version="3.5.1">
        <batchProperties class="com.mirth.connect.plugins.datatypes.raw.RawBatchProperties" version="3.5.1">
          <splitType>JavaScript</splitType>
          <batchScript></batchScript>
        </batchProperties>
      </outboundProperties>
    </transformer>
    <filter version="3.5.1">
      <elements/>
    </filter>
    <transportName>Channel Reader</transportName>
    <mode>SOURCE</mode>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <waitForPrevious>true</waitForPrevious>
  </sourceConnector>
  <destinationConnectors>
    <connector version="3.5.1">
      <metaDataId>1</metaDataId>
      <name>Destination 1</name>
      <properties class="com.mirth.connect.connectors.vm.VmDispatcherProperties" version="3.5.1">
        <pluginProperties/>
        <destinationConnectorProperties version="3.5.1">
          <queueEnabled>false</queueEnabled>
          <sendFirst>false</sendFirst>
          <retryIntervalMillis>10000</retryIntervalMillis>
          <regenerateTemplate>false</regenerateTemplate>
          <retryCount>0</retryCount>
          <rotate>false</rotate>
          <includeFilterTransformer>false</includeFilterTransformer>
          <threadCount>1</threadCount>
          <threadAssignmentVariable></threadAssignmentVariable>
          <validateResponse>false</validateResponse>
          <resourceIds class="linked-hash-map">
            <entry>
              <string>Default Resource</string>
              <string>[Default Resource]</string>
            </entry>
          </resourceIds>
          <queueBufferSize>1000</queueBufferSize>
          <reattachAttachments>true</reattachAttachments>
        </destinationConnectorProperties>
        <channelId>none</channelId>
        <channelTemplate>${message.encodedData}</channelTemplate>
        <mapVariables/>
      </properties>
      <transformer version="3.5.1">
        <elements/>
        <inboundDataType>RAW</inboundDataType>
        <outboundDataType>RAW</outboundDataType>
        <inboundProperties class="com.mirth.connect.plugins.datatypes.raw.RawDataTypeProperties" version="3.5.1">
          <batchProperties class="com.mirth.connect.plugins.datatypes.raw.RawBatchProperties" version="3.5.1">
            <splitType>JavaScript</splitType>
            <batchScript></batchScript>
          </batchProperties>
        </inboundProperties>
        <outboundProperties class="com.mirth.connect.plugins.datatypes.raw.RawDataTypeProperties" version="3.5.1">
          <batchProperties class="com.mirth.connect.plugins.datatypes.raw.RawBatchProperties" version="3.5.1">
            <splitType>JavaScript</splitType>
            <batchScript></batchScript>
          </batchProperties>
        </outboundProperties>
      </transformer>
      <responseTransformer version="3.5.1">
        <elements/>
        <inboundDataType>RAW</inboundDataType>
        <outboundDataType>RAW</outboundDataType>
        <inboundProperties class="com.mirth.connect.plugins.datatypes.raw.RawDataTypeProperties" version="3.5.1">
          <batchProperties class="com.mirth.connect.plugins.datatypes.raw.RawBatchProperties" version="3.5.1">
            <splitType>JavaScript</splitType>
            <batchScript></batchScript>
          </batchProperties>
        </inboundProperties>
        <outboundProperties class="com.mirth.connect.plugins.datatypes.raw.RawDataTypeProperties" version="3.5.1">
          <batchProperties class="com.mirth.connect.plugins.datatypes.raw.RawBatchProperties" version="3.5.1">
            <splitType>JavaScript</splitType>
            <batchScript></batchScript>
          </batchProperties>
        </outboundProperties>
      </responseTransformer>
      <filter version="3.5.1">
        <elements/>
      </filter>
      <transportName>Channel Writer</transportName>
      <mode>DESTINATION</mode>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
      <waitForPrevious>true</waitForPrevious>
    </connector>
  </destinationConnectors>
  <preprocessingScript>
    // Modify the message variable below to pre process data
    return message;
  </preprocessingScript>
  <postprocessingScript>
    // This script executes once after a message has been processed
    // Responses returned from here will be stored as &quot;Postprocessor&quot; in the response map
    return;
  </postprocessingScript>
  <deployScript>
    // This script executes once when the channel is deployed
    // You only have access to the globalMap and globalChannelMap here to persist data
    return;
  </deployScript>
  <undeployScript>
    // This script executes once when the channel is undeployed
    // You only have access to the globalMap and globalChannelMap here to persist data
    return;
  </undeployScript>
  <properties version="3.5.1">
    <clearGlobalChannelMap>true</clearGlobalChannelMap>
    <messageStorageMode>DEVELOPMENT</messageStorageMode>
    <encryptData>false</encryptData>
    <removeContentOnCompletion>false</removeContentOnCompletion>
    <removeOnlyFilteredOnCompletion>false</removeOnlyFilteredOnCompletion>
    <removeAttachmentsOnCompletion>false</removeAttachmentsOnCompletion>
    <initialState>STARTED</initialState>
    <storeAttachments>false</storeAttachments>
    <metaDataColumns>
      <metaDataColumn>
        <name>SOURCE</name>
        <type>STRING</type>
        <mappingName>mirth_source</mappingName>
      </metaDataColumn>
      <metaDataColumn>
        <name>TYPE</name>
        <type>STRING</type>
        <mappingName>mirth_type</mappingName>
      </metaDataColumn>
    </metaDataColumns>
    <attachmentProperties version="3.5.1">
      <type>None</type>
      <properties/>
    </attachmentProperties>
    <resourceIds class="linked-hash-map">
      <entry>
        <string>Default Resource</string>
        <string>[Default Resource]</string>
      </entry>
    </resourceIds>
  </properties>
  <exportData>
    <metadata>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
      <lastModified>
        <time>1508872756597</time>
        <timezone>America/Chicago</timezone>
      </lastModified>
      <pruningSettings>
        <archiveEnabled>true</archiveEnabled>
      </pruningSettings>
    </metadata>
  </exportData>
</channel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking in your Global Deploy script? From the Channels view, click Edit Global Scripts on the left-hand side.

Comment: That was it!  Someone put a log.error() in that script.